# pass two variable in getElementById function

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a code, If any one click on anchor tag then a pop-up opens. It is correctly working.

But I want some variables, in pop-up after click on anchor tag.

My PHP code are:

```
<?php
 include("connection.php");
  $query=mysql_query("select * from tenant where email1='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
 while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
 extract($result);
 ?>
 <a onClick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;"><?php echo $first_name.' '.$last_name; ?></a>?>
 <?php } ?>
```

In PHP code- some variables should be pass through onClick. By which, in the pop-up I can fetch data from table related selected variables.

My Pop-up window are:

```
   <div id="id01" class="modal">

     <form class="modal-content animate" action="xyz.php">
     <div class="imgcontainer">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>

    </div>

     <div class="container">

       <div>Content</div>

     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
```

Javascript code:

```
 <script>
 // Get the modal
 var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

 // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
 window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
 }
 }
  </script>
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Look into `data-*` attribute.

Comment: Now I updated <a onClick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;"><?php echo $first_name.' '.$last_name; ?></a>?> to <a href="#id01?m_zip=<?php echo $zip_code; ?>" onClick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;"><?php echo $first_name.' '.$last_name; ?></a>

Comment: Now pop-up opens and zip also showing as variable. But in pop-up window m_zip is showing as undefined variable. While I added extract($_REQUEST); for extract query string variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I did correctly understand you, one of the solutions consists to create a JavaScript function and call it from your PHP page by passing argument like this:

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$query=mysql_query("select * from tenant where email1='$username'") or die(mysql_error());

while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  extract($result);
?>
<a href="#" onClick="doSomething('<?php echo $zip_code; ?>')" style="width:auto;"><?php echo $first_name.' '.$last_name; ?></a>?>
<?php
}
?>
```

---

**JavaScript Code:**

You are now able to use the **arg** argument for fetching data as you want.

```
<script>
    function doSomething(arg) {

        var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

        modal.style.display = 'block';
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {

        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

More information about **functions** can be found [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

***Note:*** Please [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of using **mysql_*** functions

Comment: Now I updated <a onClick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='bloc‌​k'" style="width:auto;"><?php echo $first_name.' '.$last_name; ?></a>?> to <a href="#id01?m_zip=<?php echo $zip_code; ?>" onClick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='bloc‌​k'" style="width:auto;"><?php echo $first_name.' '.$last_name; ?></a>

Comment: Now pop-up opens and zip also showing as variable. But in pop-up window m_zip is showing as undefined variable. While I added extract($_REQUEST); for extract query string variable

Comment: What is m_zip and where is it located?

Comment: I consider m_zip as a query string variable, which will keep $zip_code value. And m_zip will variable in pop-up.  (Like:    <a href="xyz.php?m_zip=$zip_code" ></a>    )

Comment: In pop-up......query is:    <?php  extract($_REQUEST); select * from users where zip_codes='$m_zip' ?>

Comment: PHP and javascript changed like your code........In pop-up, <?php  select * from users where zip_codes='$arg' ?>

Comment: Oh no! we can chat

Comment: Only 4 reputation I have.. So I think chat is not possible here...Any other option please???